# Mode TwoWay not working for relative source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm binding a filtering option to a property in the view (NB! not in the view model and I do not wish to use it from view model in this case). The mark-up is as follows.

XAML

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{
  Binding StartDate, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
            SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_OnSelectedDateChanged" />
```

C#

```
public partial class ProgramWindow : Window
{
  private ViewModel _viewModel { get; set; }
  public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

The functionality seems to be working so when I set the field's value, the filtration performs as expected - independent of whether it's set by the date picker itself or by anything else in the code.

However, the value of the field doesn't seem to be propagated back to the control, which looks confusing because the date in the display is the old one but the records shown are clearly related to the new date.

I've tried adding the mode as *TwoWay* but that gave no difference. Suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{
  Binding StartDate, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
            SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_OnSelectedDateChanged" />
```

Comment: You have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for your `ProgramWindow` to notify change of its `StartDate` property.

Comment: @Hopeless I don't wanna...   :(  . . . . Well, if that's the only way, let it be so. You might want to post your comment as a reply so I can green check it. If you provide a small sample for future readers, there's +1 in my sleeve too.

Comment: Or you could make StartDate a dependency property...

Comment: I think you have no other option, when it comes to Binding, there is always a mechanism of change notification behind. That means if some property does not have change notification, it cannot be used in Binding as the bound property on the source side (but it can still join in some one-way Binding). This problem occurs commonly and you can find a lot of similar questions right in SO. So this question should be marked as duplicated (but this task is only for high reputation users).

Comment: @Hopeless it's on a DependencyObject, so it should be a DependencyProperty.  Binding's aren't magic, they only update automatically when the source is an INPC or DependencyProperty.

Comment: @Will I think it's another way, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged is also OK if the property is just for Binding. DependencyProperty is something overkill because it supports Binding, Animation, Trigger, ...

Comment: @Hopeless meh, I think implementing a (functionally redundant) interface when it isn't needed is overkill...

Comment: @Will you'll take much more time to declare DP rather than implementing  INPC. As I said it depends totally on your the purpose of using the property.

Comment: @Hopeless don't be... hopeless?  I've got a snippet for DPs that takes less time to use than creating a normal property, let alone an INPC-enabled one.  Not my fault people are poorly prepared :)

Comment: @Hopeless I'm with you because before you know it, along comes `NoobieUser` (x100000), reads the DP solution and uses it once... then realizes they could use it again since it was quick and easy.... then again... and again... and now their entire project/design is `DP`s when in reality following MVVM would've probably solved it to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the property a DependencyProperty to notify UI of updates:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StartDateProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("StartDate", typeof(DateTime), typeof(ProgramWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.MinValue),
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public string StartDate
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetValue(StartDateProperty) as DateTime;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(StartDateProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `ProgramWindow` and raise the property changed event.

Comment: @hopeless I think this is a perfect opportunity to present yours versus Glens. It turned out to be a very informative question. Comparing two good approaches? Yummy for coders. Weird that the question hasn't been upvoted yet, frankly speaking...

Comment: I think the reason it hasn't been upvoted is that it has been asked a thousand times before and the answer could easily be found with some simple search engine searches.

Comment: You need to have an understanding of `INPC` and `DataContext` to begin with if you want a second solution. Posting a tutorial/example of proper MVVM would be your alternative answer, but no one is going to want to take the time to understand your specific design and tailor a solution that only might work for you.  Therefore, this solution is going to be the quickest and easiest.

Comment: Posting it with the "mvvm" and "data-binding" tags means it's also off-topic. Calling code-behind in the manner in which it's done here is not MVVM, and INotifyPropertyChanged is the fundamental mechanism upon which WPF data-binding is based. Saying "I want to accomplish X but I want to hack it my way instead of how it's designed to be done" means you'll be back in another day or two when you hit the next hurdle. And then again. And again. It becomes increasingly frustrating for the people trying to help you, especially when it's entirely avoidable by doing things properly from the start.

Comment: @MarkFeldman Well said. I see so many of those questions and then I see the poster coming back shortly after looking for the next hack down the long road of defying convention even after you try to steer them in the right direction. Tiring.

Comment: @MarkFeldman I'm using MVVM (except for the date but otherwise in the window) and I'm binding data. How come you feel that it's off-topic, please? I'm facing a situation where it's not very appropriate for this specific control to use MVVM, so I'd appreciate if you could offer me benefit of doubt. It **might** be that the frustration you're experiencing isn't called for in this particular case, perhaps? I'm sure you're aware that sometimes  coders are facing reality where whining about "right from the start" isn't applicable. Your comment didn't make **me** any wiser, at least.

Comment: @GlenThomas I appreciate that you're providing an answer, despite it being tiring. In fact, it's this kind of remark that makes others (or at least me) to review my code and approach once again. After all, if you feel that I'm going the wrong way, perhaps it'd behoove me to look at it from a different angle. But that's a matter for code review. As for your contribution, I'm accepting it and even awarding it +1 because of the example conforming to the premises. Thanks.

Comment: @Konrad breaking of the MVVM pattern occurs by your decision to do filtering "not in the view model" and also by your use of code-behind (i.e. DatePicker_OnSelectedDateChanged). I apologise if I came across a bit strong but it was a direct response to the comments" I do not wish to use it from view model" and "I don't wanna" regarding the use of INotiftyPropertyChanged. This is why your question has been down-voted: you're seeking a solution that adheres to the MVVM paradigm whilst simultaneously stipulating constraints that specifically violate it. Makes it very difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of doing this in MVVM, let's create a window with two date pickers and a list of dates. Selecting a date in either date picker should cause the other one to change as well (to demonstrate that 2-way binding is working), and selecting either should cause the next 2-weeks worth of dates to be added to the listbox. Here's the XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate}"/>
    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate}"/>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredDates}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Here's the view model:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private DateTime _StartDate;
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get { return this._StartDate; }
        set
        {
            this._StartDate = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.StartDate);
            ApplyFilter();
        }
    }

    private IList<DateTime> _FilteredDates;
    public IList<DateTime> FilteredDates
    {
        get { return this._FilteredDates; }
        set { this._FilteredDates = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.FilteredDates); }
    }

    private void ApplyFilter()
    {
        this.FilteredDates = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>(
            Enumerable.Range(0, 14)
            .Select(i => this.StartDate.AddDays(i)));
    }
```

ViewModelBase is a class in the MVVM Lite library, which you can add via NuGet.

Notice there is no code-behind at all, in this simple case you don't even need to subscribe to events. When the user selects a date the StartDate member in the view model will get called and it will call ApplyFilter which will in turn create a filtered list of dates.

This may not be exactly what you're trying to do but it should illustrate the point. First of all, this code is entirely data-driven. Anything else can bind to StartDate and work properly with everything else bound to it without having to know what those things are. Secondly, there is no code-behind. It has achieved good separation of concerns by placing all view logic in the view model where it belongs, with the view consisting of only loosely-bound XAML objects. Finally there is nothing to stop you creating the viewmodel without the view, which means this code and it's filtering behaviour etc can be unit tested.

To specifically answer your question though the reason this code works and yours doesn't is because of INotifyPropertyChanged and the use of RaisePropertyChanged, which you will need to implement yourself irrespective of whether or not you choose to use proper MVVM.